# How can custom allocator know if a pointer points to an array?

Tags: c++, allocator

I could have misunderstood something about some concepts on allocator. But I really don't know why we need a argument of `std::size_t` to be passed to `allocate` to indicate the number of objects to be allocated. Is the argument used to allocate memory regions like arrays or vectors?

*If they are*, then how can my custom allocator know if the previously returned pointer points to a region or just an object? Is my allocator responsible to keep a record of those pointers?

*If they are not*, then why do we need that argument?

Comment: Does this help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`allocator_traits<YourAllocator<T>>::allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate) is expected to allocate memory for a contiguous sequence of N objects of type `T`. The N is provided by the `size_t` parameter.

> If they are, then how can my custom allocator know if the previously returned pointer points to a region or just an object?

What "previously returned pointer"?

Your allocator will be told when to allocate and when to *deallocate* memory. When deallocation happens, [it will be told what N was for the allocation that is being deallocated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/deallocate). Your allocator doesn't need to keep track of any pointers.

Comment: My bad, and because of that there was a horrible memory leak when passed to STL containers. I did write the signature as `void deallocate(pointer ptr, std::size_t dummy=1)` :-\ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about std::allocator here. The documentation is pretty clear:

> `T* std::allocator::allocate(std::size_t n);`
>
> Allocates n * sizeof(T) bytes of uninitialized storage [...]

So the answer to your question would be: Yes, the argument is used to allocate memory regions like arrays or vectors.

And for your follow up question: No, you don't need to keep track of the returned pointers, because `std::allocator::deallocate` is guaranteed to be called with the same `n` as `std::allocator::allocate` was for any of the returned pointers.

> `void std::allocator::deallocate( T* p, std::size_t n );`
>
> Deallocates the storage referenced by the pointer p, which must be a pointer obtained by an earlier call to allocate().
>   The argument n must be equal to the first argument of the call to allocate() that originally produced p; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I don't see any guarantee here.  You need to pass the same pointer that was created with allocate and you need to pass the correct size otherwise it is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think they are refering to the guarantee offered by standard containers: if you are creating a custom allocator for `std::vector`, then `std::vector` will always (in theory) respect the contracts of your allocator and call `deallocate` with the same `p` and `n` as the ones used in `allocate`.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Ah.  That makes sense.